# Why does display output affects motors?

Tags: ev3

I'm making a simple program with LEGO EV3 Education. It makes a little tank to follow a black line over a white-ish floor.

Here it is:

[[image]]

This works very smooth: it makes the tank follow the EDGE of the line and substantially takes in account the amount of light the sensor recevies.
Black is 11, White is 75: if the light is near 75, then take the power of the B (left) motor higher than the C (right) motor. if the light is near 11, then take the power of C motor higher than B. Otherwise, make C and B power similar.

I want now to add some output on the display, like this:

[image]

The idea is: if B power is between C+10 and C-10, then show a forward arrow. else if: if B < C show Right arrow, else Left arrow.

Problem is that, adding this code, the tank doesn't move straight anymore! C and B motor ,on a stright line, alternate power making the robot zig zagging the line.

Why does an output operation on the display affects motors power?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it takes time to write to the display. The motor speed cannot be changed until the display blocks have finished and your loop repeats.

Try this instead... create a second loop in parallel to the first that handles the display. You will need a new logic variable to send information from the motor loop to the display loop.

[image: first two loops]
[image: third loop]

Comment: I tried, same result! What do you mean with "new logic variable"? I used the same "B-Power" and "C-Power" variable that I'm using in the main motor loop

Comment: I have added screenshots to show what I mean. I imagine that it would be better to move the math blocks from the motor loop to the display loop, then you wouldn't need the "Forward" variable.